# How to configure the CORS module for multiple domains?

Tags: javascript, 8

I have JSON content I want to deliver to multiple domains. I have installed the [CORS](https://www.drupal.org/project/cors) module. I have configured to deliver to one domain like this:

```
*|<mirror>,http://www.other-domain.com
```

This works. However, I want to configure for a list of domains and can't work out how to configure that. The following doesn't work:

```
*|<mirror>,http://www.other-domain.com,https://www.and-another.com
```

Nor does

```
*|<mirror>,http://www.other-domain.com
*|<mirror>,https://www.and-another.com
```

How do I configure this?

Comment: This information doesn't really help. It's too specific to the module. You should read about CORS and what the expected output of headers should be. Specifically the output should either be `*` or `https://www.example.com`. Include the HTTP Request and HTTP Response headers.

Comment: It does not look like the module and patch implement CORS correctly. The response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set to a comma-delimited string when it must be exactly 1 origin or `*`. If I use the configuration `*|https://www.example.com,https://www.drupal.org` and `curl -vvv -H "Origin: https://www.example.com" https://something.ply.st/node/1.json`, then I get `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com, https://www.drupal.org`, which is not valid. Trying a preflight request results in the same invalid response header.

Comment: I've resolved the issue by using /directory/*|* Whilst not ideal it is the only way I can get it to work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report and needs to be handled in the issue queue on Drupal.org

Answer (score 1):

Upon further investigation, this seems to be an issue with the CORS module, and has been patched, so hopefully fixed in future versions.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2780297

Comment: Still not working - I applied the patch but it is still not working...